# Проверьте пожалуйста - придаточное определительное?

Tags: синтаксис

*Любовь – все, **что делается обнаженно.***

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще-то это местоименно-определительное предложение (частный вид придаточных определительных), местоименная пара "всё - что", в роли определяемого слова выступает местоимение.

Сравнить: Любовь - то действие, что делается обнаженно. Придаточное определительное раскрывает содержание указательного слова ТО.

Comment: "*Придаточное определительное раскрывает содержание указательного слова ТО.*" - а разве не слова "действие"?  Можно ведь опустить "то"...

Comment: ... Или надо было бы использовать "которое" вместо "что"?

Comment: Это ничего не меняет, местоимение ЧТО заменяет местоимение КОТОРОЕ. Указательное слово здесь факультативно, важно, что определение относится к существительному, а не к местоимению

Comment: И что насчёт моего первого коментария?